# Function of two angles of rotation that increments the first to make it closer to the second

Tags: javascript, math, refactoring

Imagine a turret on a tank. The user can specify the angle of rotation they want the turret to be at, but it takes a while to swing round, as it can only rotate so quickly.

I basically need a function that can take the current angle (of rotation) and the target angle, and return a number that is a little bit closer to the target than the current angle.

The function must not cause the turret to rotate the 'long way around'. For example, if it's currently at 5 radians and the target is 0, then the return value should be greater than 5.

I have this so far, but it does not quite work correctly. Doing `yaw(0, 6)` returns `-0.01` when it should return `6.273...` (2π - 0.01).

```
const { sign, abs, PI } = Math;

const yaw = function(current, target, increment=0.01) {

    const distance = current - target;
    const rotation = abs(distance) > PI ? sign(distance) : -sign(distance);

    return current + rotation * increment;
};
```

**Edit**: This works, but it seems pretty inelegant. Is there a cleaner solution?

```
const yaw = function(current, target, increment=0.01) {

    const distance = current - target;
    const rotation = abs(distance) > PI ? sign(distance) : -sign(distance);
    return (current + rotation * increment + TAU) % TAU;
};
```

Comment: I'm thinking to add TAU to the result, so it subtracts negative amounts, and overflows by TAU with positive results, then use modulo TAU to cancel the overflow.

Comment: What is TAU? Also, `yaw(0, 1)` looks to be 0.01, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry: `TAU == 2 * PI`. The result of `yaw(0, 1)` should be `0.01`. You're correct. The downvote put me off as I was editing that bit. I'll fix it now.

Comment: It seems all you need is to add a statement at the end to test if the result is <0, and add `2*PI`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got it working, and it's pretty fast. I just wish it was less ugly, and know that a mathematician could do a better job of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had `sin(current)`, `cos(current)`, `sin(target)` and `cos(target)` (or some positive multiples of these), then the following would be nice and elegant:

```
rotation = sign(sinTarget*cosCurrent - sinCurrent*cosTarget)
```

It uses the sign of the determinant of the matrix formed by the 2d vectors in current and target direction. That determinant is proportional to the *oriented* area of the parallelogram spanned by these vectors, with the sign indicating the direction.

If you don't have these trigonometric functions already computed for some purpose, then computing them for the sake of this case distinction is probably a waste of resources, compared to what you have.